# Why single authored scientific papers addressed as "We"?

Tags: pronouns, academic-writing

I have come across a couple of single authored scientific papers. For example, see [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1536414.1536440), [this](http://ieee-focs.org/FOCS-2018-Papers/pdfs/59f259.pdf), [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.585.7341&rep=rep1&type=pdf), etc.

Why does the author refer to him/her as "We" instead of "I" since there is just a single author?

Comment: You might find this answer on [academia.se] helpful: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2948

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather dated style of writing scientific papers.

Scientists try to avoid the personal and individual when writing papers. The aim is to get a neutral presentation of facts.  To this end scientist will write "we" to mean either "I and other people in the lab" or "I and you the reader".

For example

> We fed the chicks on a mix of proteins to test their development

(probably there were other people in the lab who did the feeding)

In the examples you link to, it is clear that a relatively junior researcher is referring to "We" to mean "I and other in my department".

On the other hand:

> We can calculate the cohomology and find it is trival.

Here "we" probably means "I and you, the reader".